# Parsing Recieved or Read Serial Port Data c++

Tags: c++, checksum

i need some pointers 1st time experience with serial port programming. I have a serial port data, how do i parse this data so that i can process the individual element for storage and report generation.

command sent to serial port
`comand[]= FA0130AB`
comand with crc
`FA xx xx xx xx xx` = command+CRC

Serial port received data
`FA xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx`

required way to process data
`[portID| Length | Response|Price | Volume | Amount |Totalvol | Status |Check CRC]`

Where
`

```
[portID]=xx
[Length] = xx 
[Response]= xx
[Price ]=xx xx xx  3byte with BCD format
[Volume]=xx xx xx xx  4 bytes with BCD format
[Amount]=xx xx xx xx  4 bytes with BCD format
[Totalvol]= xx xx xx xx xx  5 bytes with BCD format
```

`

i want to be able to manipulate the serial port data to do the following
1) split the serial port data
2) get individual element price volume, amount and totalvol convert them from BCD to Hex to ACII or Decimal for storage and reporting

am splitting the serial data with this function
now how do i get the differentiate the HEX values from the BCD so i can process individually.
any pointers will be appreciated.

```
std::vector<std::string> explode(
    std::string delimiter, 
    std::string source, 
    int limit = std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
{
    // PHP returns FALSE in this case, but C++ doesn't handle variant types well, and a
    // reasonable facsimile of FALSE is tricky with std::vector<>, so we'll just throw.
    if (delimiter.empty())
        throw std::invalid_argument("Empty delimiter in explode()");
    // Sanitize the limit to something meaningful
    if (limit == 0)
        limit = 1;
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    // Handle the simple case of zero delimiter matches
    if (source.find(delimiter) == std::string::npos) {
        // PHP returns array() if limit is negative, array(source) if limit is positive
        if (limit > 0)
            result.push_back(source);
        return result;
    }
    std::vector<std::string>::size_type begin = 0;
    std::vector<std::string>::size_type end = 0;
    // Explode up to any positive limit, exclusive
    while (end != std::string::npos) {
        if (limit > 0 && result.size() == limit - 1) {
            // PHP populates the last element (ie. result[limit - 1]) with the remaining 
            // string when limit is positive and less than the number of total tokens.
            result.push_back(source.substr(begin));
            break;
        }
        /*
            Conventional C++ manual string tokenization.
        */
        std::vector<std::string>::size_type substr_len = std::string::npos;
        std::vector<std::string>::size_type next_tok = std::string::npos;
        end = source.find_first_of(delimiter, begin);
        if (end != std::string::npos) {
            substr_len = end - begin;
            next_tok = end + delimiter.size();
        }
        result.push_back(source.substr(begin, substr_len));
        begin = next_tok;
    }
    // Negative limits trim that amount from the right side of the result. It's
    // easier to do this after the explode loop because we don't need to retain
    // unexploded parts of the string like with a positive limit.
    if (limit < 0) {
        limit = abs(limit);
        if (limit < result.size())
            result.resize(result.size() - limit);
        else {
            // PHP returns array() if all items or more would be trimed
            result.clear();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Reading from the serial port is just reading a bunch of bytes. You have to know the format of the data. You might be surprised to know that there is no universal data format used by all serial port devices in the world to send data. You need to actually know the format of the serial port data, then parse it. You have not explained exactly how to translate your hex dump into the format you want. Unfortunately, on stackoverflow.com, you are the only one who can figure this out, because only you know what exactly is attached to your serial port, and how it sends its data.

Comment: And if your question is really "how do i get the differentiate the HEX values from the BCD", then this has nothing to do with anybody's serial port, so you can simply get rid of that part of your question, in order to avoid confusion, and explain exactly the raw data you have as input, and the expected output you want to get.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for your timely response and pointers, however i have edited the response to show what was sent and received by the serial port communication i want to be able to split the string received to the format shown above and convert them to their various ascii format for reporting and storage

Comment: No, I am afraid you have not explained anything. You've shown that the initial raw data is "FA 01 0B B0 15 12 28 11 54..." and somehow you expect to get "[portID] =01[Length] =0x14" from that, etc. There is absolutely nothing to indicate how you get from start to finish here. If someone new nothing about what you're doing, they'll have no idea. Ok, portid is 01, and the second received byte is 01. But what the heck does "FA" mean, and so on. Don't just dump a bunch of code with the only explanation of "it doesn't work", without explaining HOW it's supposed to work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for the pointers again. i have edited the question to show the serial port communication making it easier to understand what aiming for. the  "[portID] =xx [Length] =xx" ... are the combination of what am to expect from the serial  port response. i want to split them and convert them to their ascii format for storage

Comment: No, I'm afraid it is still not possible to determine what your actual question is. Now you've removed all data, but you still provide what you expect to see on output. Try to imagine, for a moment, that somebody doesn't know anything about your serial port device, or it's format, and they read this question? Would they have any idea what you're trying to do? Of course not. Nobody does. That's why nobody is giving you any answers. If you do not know how to ask a question that someone else can understand, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to give you an answer.

Comment: I think he did an okay job at what he is trying to parse from this, he shows that he has a his long input and below that he shows that it needs to be broken up into chunks with the given byte sizes. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think he simply wants a way to be able to break this up. That or each of the tags such as [Length] and [Price] have their own hex values that he wants to be able to search for within the stream of data.